# How to display the total value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and ggplot2 to display data acquired from ndnSim, When I run the flowing code, it displays HopCount 4 and 2 at time 10sec respectively and 4 and 4 in time 11sec. But I want to have it display as 6 (sum of HopCount) in time 10sec and similarly sum of HopCount 8 for 11sec...and so on. How to do that, Please help me.

```
Time    Node    AppId SeqNo Type      HopCount
10.0057 leaf-1  1     0     LastDelay        4
10.0057 leaf-1  1     0     FullDelay        4
10.0066 leaf-1  1     1     LastDelay        2
10.0066 leaf-1  1     1     FullDelay        2
11.0029 leaf-2  2     0     LastDelay        2
11.0029 leaf-2  2     0     FullDelay        2
11.0057 leaf-1  1     0     LastDelay        4
11.0057 leaf-1  1     0     FullDelay        4
11.0057 leaf-1  1     0     LastDelay        4
11.0057 leaf-1  1     0     FullDelay        4
```

My original code is

```
data = read.table ("app-delays-trace.txt", header=T)
data$Node = factor (data$Node)
data$AppId <- factor(data$AppId)
data$HopCount <- data$HopCount
data$Type = factor (data$Type)

# exlude irrelevant types

data = subset (data, Type %in% c("FullDelay"))
data = subset (data, Node %in% c("leaf-1"))
data = subset (data, AppId %in% c("1"))

# combine stats from all faces

data.combined = summaryBy (. ~ Time + Node + AppId + Type, data=data, FUN=sum)
g.root <- ggplot (data.combined) +
geom_point (aes (x=Time, y=HopCount.sum, color=Type), size=0.5) +
geom_line (aes (x=Time, y=HopCount.sum, color=Type), size=0.5) +
ylab ("Hop Count")
print (g.root)
png ("app-delay-1.png", width=500, height=250)
print (g.root)
dev.off ()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to study how we have edited your question. It was quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably look for `aggregate`. the `summaryby` you're trying is probably analogous to `data.combined = aggregate(. ~ Time + Node + AppId + Type, data=data, FUN=sum)` and based on your verbal description, I think you want to do

```
data$TimeFloor <-  floor(data$Time)
data.combined = aggregate(. ~ TimeFloor + Node + AppId + Type, data=data, FUN=sum)
```

Output:

```
> data.combined
  TimeFloor   Node    Time AppId SeqNo Type HopCount
1        10 leaf-1 20.0123     2     1    2        6
2        11 leaf-1 22.0114     2     0    2        8
```

Comment: I am getting this error message while runing the code                                                                    g.root <- ggplot (data.combined) +
+ geom_point (aes (x=TimeFloor, y=HopCount.sum, color=Type), size=0.5) +
+ geom_line (aes (x=TimeFloor, y=HopCount.sum, color=Type), size=0.5) +
+ ylab ("Hop Count")
> print (g.root)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'HopCount.sum' not found
> png ("app-delay-1.png", width=500, height=250)
> print (g.root)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'HopCount.sum' not found
> dev.off ()
null device 
          1

Comment: Exactly what it says, it can't find `HopCount.sum`. Hint: look at the column names of `data.combined`.

Comment: The Column names are same..its HopCount. But I dont know what is the problem with HopCount.sum?

Comment: I don't know which language's syntax you're borrowing. There's nothing as hopcount.sum which is why ggplot() can't find it. Just pass hopcount instead, since that's the actual name of your column. I would also advise a bit of googling, being new to R is not an excuse to not being able to understand what to do with this error message.